# How to use GPU for OpenCL from command line remote login

Tags: command-line, gpu, remote-login

I use OpenCL accelerated math on my workstation which I can only access remotely via command line from Windows. I have no desire to have a VNC desktop or tunnel X through ssh.

When I am not logged in to the desktop on my workstation, I am unable to use the GPU for anything. For example, `clinfo` hangs. `strace clinfo` shows that it looks in my expired `~/.Xauthority` file and was then unable to use the magic cookie. It then hangs polling for the non-existing magic cookie.

I thought one solution might be to trigger Ubuntu to log in a user via the remote shell, but after searching around I don't think this is possible with automatic login (which I do not want to do). Another option might be some cleverness with `~/.Xauthority` but I really don't know how the magic cookie thing works at all.

Comment: http://wiki.tiker.net/OpenCLHowTo#Running_OpenCL_code_remotely_on_AMD_GPUs_.28via_SSH.29